# Review Board : How do I post a single file for review using cvs and review board

Tags: cvs, review-board

I have made changes to lot of files under a directory. Out of those files I need to add a single file for review using Review Board. If I do

```
$rbt post src/foo.c
```

I get a message like 
CRITICAL: CVS does not support passing in a single revision

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In rbtools 0.6, the command line arguments were modified to require a `-I` for passing individual files. So the command would become the following:

```
$rbt post -I src/foo.c
```